# Higer order function for binomial

Tags: python

Suppose I am given this

```
 def sum(term, a, next, b):
        if (a>b):
            return 0
        else:
            return term(a) + sum(term, next(a), next, b)
```

and

```
def poly_while(coefficients, x):
    i, result = 0, 0
    while i < len(coefficients):
        result += coefficients[i] * (x ** i)
        i = i + 1
    return result
```

I want to write a HOF that uses `sum`

```
def poly(coefficients, x):
    return sum(lambda a: coefficients[a]*(x**(a)),0, lambda x: x + 1, len(coefficients))
```

What is the mistake here?

Here are the inputs

```
poly((1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 3) #1(3^0) + 2(3^1) +3(3^2) +4(3^3) + 5(3^4) = 547
poly((1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 1)  #15

poly((), 3) #0
```

Comment: Note that both `sum` and `next` are the names of built-in functions in Python. While it's not forbidden to reuse the names for other purposes, it is probably a bad idea to do so (you may confuse yourself or others).

Answer (score 0):

The following method works as expected:

```
def poly(coefficients, x):
    return sum([i*(x**(i-1)) for i in coefficients])

>>> print poly((1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 3)
>>> print poly((1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 1)
>>> print poly((), 3)
547
15
0
```

Comment: `sum` can work with a generator expression: `sum(i*(x**(i-1)) for i in coefficients)`

Comment: You're using the built-in `sum`, not the `sum` the questioner is asking about.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting with your version of `poly` has to do with the bound checking. `sum` only stops recursing when `a > b`, but the value you're supplying for `b` is `len(coefficients)`. This leads the code to try to access `coefficients[len(coefficients)]` which gives an IndexError.

You need to either change the `>` in `sum` to `>=`, or change the `b` value passed by `poly` to `len(coefficients) - 1`.

A final note: This style of coding is not terribly Pythonic. It's much more common to use iteration and generator expressions or list comprehensions than to use `lambda`s and higher order functions.

Also, you should probably avoid reusing the names `sum` and `next`, which both belong to built-in functions in Python. You'll tend to confuse people reading the code (including, perhaps, yourself in the future) if you use the names for something else.